# Twig - loop default value

Tags: symfony, twig

I am trying to print array from the cotroller into the twig temlate. I want to print "-" whenever array is NULL. My problem is that in for-loop case it writes nothing, however single row working fine. Is there some simple way how to do it correctly?

this is not working as i expected

```
{% for key  in keywords|default('-') %} 
    {{ key~', '}} 
{% endfor %}
```

this is working

```
{{ key |default('-')}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `{% else %}` construct on a for loop to do something else if the array is null:

```
{% for key  in keywords %} 
    {{ key~', '}} 
{% else %}
    -
{% endfor %}
```

See the documentation [here](https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-else-clause).

Comment: My comment doesn't make any sense I mean't `{% else %}-{% endfor %}` indeed, just found it strange to use twig to just output a string